# Can't Start Golang Prog Via Upstart

Tags: go, ubuntu-12.04, upstart

I can't get my golang prog to run via upstart.

Here is my proj dir--

```
 /go
   /src
     /print.io
       /geo
         main.go
       /geodomain
         [.. files ..]
```

I have my gopath set to the `/go` dir above.

Within the `/geo` folder i can run `go run main.go` and it works.

However, with the following upstart configuration its logging `main.go:8:2: import "print.io/geodomain": cannot find package`--

Why doesnt it work from upstart like it does when i run the command manually?

```
description "go-server"
author "micah smith"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])

stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn

script
        chdir ~/go/src/print.io/geo/
        exec go run main.go
end script
```

Comment: Does it work if you cd to the `geo` directory then run `go run main.go`?

Comment: @deft_code yes it does

Comment: Is it possible that, when invoked through Upstart, the `GOPATH` isn't set? Try compiling your program (`go build`) and putting it on your normal `PATH`.

Comment: @SashaCrofter that was it! crazy strange

Comment: Gotta be really careful with environment variables around Go, unfortunately, so I stopped using `go run` a while ago, and just compile everything I expect to use. I'll resumbit my comment as an answer, so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumbitted from comment:

> Is it possible that, when invoked through Upstart, the `GOPATH` isn't set? Try compiling your program (`go build`) and putting it on your normal `PATH`.