# Golang - command "go" not found when running via Upstart

Tags: ubuntu, go

I'm trying to run a go command via "upstart" on my ubuntu.

My upstart script is

```
script
  go run /home/myhome/gocode/src/program/hello.go
end script
```

It's not working and I checked the log file and it says

```
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: go: not found
```

I can run "go" on command line using any user name. How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is your go binary located? I guess upstart sets PATH to the default value which does not include custom paths.

Comment: This can't work. Upstart does not set PATH or GOROOT.

Comment: I would think upstart lets you set some environment variables yourself though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `go run` to run your Go program. You should compile it with `go build` and then use Upstart to run that.

Use `exec /path/to/your/binary` instead.

Also see:
- [Can't Start Golang Prog Via Upstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102349/cant-start-golang-prog-via-upstart)
- https://coderwall.com/p/iekaog
- https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-nuts/uBrN-G7anKg (lots of examples)

Answer (score 2):

Type `which go` as another user to find out the full path to the go executable.  Then, in your upstart script, replace `go` with the full path (e.g. `/usr/local/go/bin`).

I am not sure why you are having this problem, but maybe the upstart user has a different path than normal users (i.e. it might include `/sbin` instead of `/usr/bin`).

Comment: I added "/usr/local/go/bin" in the "etc/profile" - doesn't that make it system-wide? But that didn't work either. I also tried on "/etc/environment" - no success.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  I suggested one thing that would have a good chance of working, the OP strangely did something else, and someone downvoted it.

Comment: wan't me, sorry for the late reply. I did try "which go" and tried the full path on the upstart script - to no avail. In the end, I knew I shouldn't run go program via "go run". So I built it and then used the upstart to call it - that did the trick (though it's still mystery to me why things weren't picking up initially)